# Change datagridview selected row font

Tags: c#

Is there any option in my datagridview propertiew which i can change font only on selected row? 
Or i should do it manually?

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
            if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
            {
                e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DefaultCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property like

```
dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = 
           new Font(DataGridView.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution to your problem.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Another one that can also work for you.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: This is C#, no JQuery

Comment: You edited and anyway you still do not provide a solution

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán Solution provided you are having bad impact on my reputation dear.

Comment: I cannot try the code now but @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán, can u say why it won't work ?

Comment: Two negative votes and I have not had to see.
If I could vote now miso, I would vote positive to the other post, but I can not vote up to 2 hours

Comment: I did the favour @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán

Comment: @zackraiyan It's simple and obvious, tell me, does this code select a specific row and change its source?
Do you think it does?
And also, how do you explain the negative votes?

Comment: ow wait ..u are right ... checked the code again :) ... its not what the OP wants atleast

Comment: @zackraiyan Could you explain what OP is?

Comment: isn't OP the one who posted the qs ? I guess that's what they are called with here

Comment: hey wait ... @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán,what is the problem with the 2nd part of the code ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I mean what those acronyms mean

Comment: @zackraiyan Well, nothing, someday I'll break it ;-)

Comment: @zackraiyan This code changes the color, but not the font.

Do you see something that as in the question puts it in Bold?

Comment: the answer is obviously a good answer , don't tell me the OP can't modify it to change the font style ?!!

Comment: though i should agree that the first portion of the answer is completely useless in this case :(

Comment: @zackraiyan Well, it's what you told me the other day, an answer that a NEW USER or a newbie does not understand, or that the answer itself is not explained well, is not a good answer

Comment: @zackraiyan And one more thing, that negative vote is NOT mine

Comment: oh good point sir :) but i called this one a good one is because u said the code wouldn't work ....

Comment: negative votes are there to inspire us so that we learn more :) ... Don't worry if u get/give one